# having issues rendering elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an online test with 4 screens: html file, react/javascript file, css file, and the output which currently shows the html document.

I tried adding a REACTdom command to the .js code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<p>hi</p>,document.getElementById('exercise1'));
```

and of course in the html I added a div with that ID

```
<div id="exercise1"></div>
```

However it is not rendering, and it's complaining about that reactDom.render line.

[image]

How can I properly render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include React or just ReactDOM? you need React for JSX

Look at the html settings here:
https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/hello-world

[image]

Comment: I'm using jsfiddle.net but I don't think I'm not sure I'm supposed to use JSX. Is it possible to do rendering without JSX?

Comment: you can but I don't recommend it: `React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello world')`  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html you will still need React anyway...
JSX comes with React. it is basically taking your <p>Hi</p> and concerts it to javascript. You have to include React if you want to use React.

Comment: SOLVED. Turns out I was missing those two external scripts from your pic. Yes I will continue with JSX